# How do I clean SqlDependency from SQL Server memory?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sqldependency

How do I clean up the SQL Server to get rid of expired `SqlDependency` objects? After I receive the event from the `SqlDepedency` object, I need to create a new one before I can get a new event. However, the memory use of the SQL Server process climbs until it runs out of the allowed memory (SQL Server Express). How do I get rid of old queries?

Code:

```
// Func: RegisterTableListener
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabseEventConnectionString))
{
if (cmd == null)
{
    cmd = cn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT HostName, LastStatus, LastDetails, xml FROM dbo.[SystemTable]";
}

lock (cmd)
{
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Notification = null;

    //  creates a new dependency for the SqlCommand
    if (dep == null)
        dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
    //  creates an event handler for the notification of data
    //      changes in the database.
    dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);


    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
    // code here to read
    }
}
}

// Func dependency_OnChange
//SqlDependency dep = sender as SqlDependency;
dep.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
RegisterTableListener();
```

Comment: How are you creating the `SqlDependency` objects? Please post your code. Are you disposing of them properly?

Comment: Ill update my comment with code when I get to work tomorrow.

Sudo:
SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
dep.OnChange += fun;

SqlDependency does not implement IDisposable

Comment: I have updated with code. Even when I run just one instance of a SqlDepdency and call Stop and Start each time, memory climbs. I am clueless as to what is happening.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a specific behavior of Microsoft SqlDependency class. Even though you call SqlDependency.Stop() method, release SqlCommand and SqlConnection - it still keeps conversation groups (sys.conversation_groups) and conversation endpoints (sys.conversation_endpoints) in the database. It looks like SQL Server loads every conversation endpoint and uses all allowed memory. [Here](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.UnitTests/SqlDependencyTest.cs) tests that prove it. So, to clean all unused conversation endpoints and release all occupied memory you have to start this SQL code for your database:

```
DECLARE @ConvHandle uniqueidentifier
DECLARE Conv CURSOR FOR
SELECT CEP.conversation_handle FROM sys.conversation_endpoints CEP
WHERE CEP.state = 'DI' or CEP.state = 'CD'
OPEN Conv;
FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
    END CONVERSATION @ConvHandle WITH CLEANUP;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle;
END
CLOSE Conv;
DEALLOCATE Conv;
```

Also, SqlDependency doesn't give you an opportunity to receive ALL changes of the table. So, you don't receive notification about changes during SqlDependency resubscription.

To avoid all these problems I'd used another open source realization of SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive events about changes of the table. This is an usage example:

```
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the meaning of this line WHERE CEP.state = 'DI' or CEP.state = 'CD'. what r u trying to do. please help me to understand. thanks

Comment: @Mou `DI` means "DisconnectedInbound", `CD` means "Closed". Conversations endpoints with this marks don't have lifetime being set by `SqlDependency`. It means that they will be in a database until you clean them up forcefully. According to the article http://rusanu.com/2014/03/31/how-to-prevent-conversation-endpoint-leaks/ (in the end) it is a right way to clean up the old conversation endpoints.

Comment: does it mean if i use this sql `WHERE CEP.state = 'DI' or CEP.state = 'CD'` then old conversation will remove ?

Comment: @Mou Here is another evidence of memory leaks and inventor comments about it. In the end you can find a similar solution. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/KtJZ0cdVk7k And here is unit tests which show that `SqlDependency` keeps unclosed or lifetime absent conversation endpoints in a database. https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.UnitTests/SqlDependencyTest.cs

Comment: @Mou The article from Rusanu that I mentioned above gives an example of cleaning old conversation endpoints with `CD` state only. But in my experience `DI` endpoints keep being in a database also.

Comment: good patters using SqlDependency ?