# I want my database (SQL) to notify or push updates to client application

Tags: sql-server, push-notification, service-broker, sqldependency, query-notifications

I was developing this application on `VB.net 2010` and `SQL 2008`.
I wanted the clients to be notified for updates on the db, and the application used to check the db for changes in the specified minute using a timer, which really is not efficient. I read about `query notification`, `sqldependency`, `service broker`, but then I read something that said they might not be efficient if I have 100 clients and I'm using query notifications to push notifications to  my application.
Would someone help out on what I should do, and how I can do it (would be really helpful if examples are available). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27):

Query Notification will push to a Service Broker service, not directly to your application. See [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to understand how it works. Your application is waiting for notifications by posting a [`WAITFOR(RECEIVE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx) statement *on the database*. Which implies that each of the 100 clients is occupying one SQL Server worker thread (which are limited, see [`max worker threads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) option). I've seen this working in production with +1000 clients (after bumping up the max worker threads option) but I would advise *against* it.

My recommendation would be to have **one** service monitoring for change, using SqlDependency/QueryNotifications. This service would then push notifications, using WCF for instance, to all your running apps. You would subscribe to generic changes (`the table Foo was changed`), not to specific ones (`the row x in table Foo was inserted`).

As a general rule SqlDependency/Query Notifications can only inform you that data has changed, but it won't push the *new* data. The application must refresh its local datasets by running the queries again, once notified.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class - it has the [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/) with memory leaks. Hovewer, you can use an open source realization of the SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses a database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive events about the table changes. This is an usage example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

With SqlDependecyEx you are able to monitor just UPDATE, avoiding DELETE and INSERT. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t update databse manually and all data manipulation are in your application, you should to detect changes in application service layer or business layer instead of db in case you depend on database technology and going to other databases will be difficult.
In other hand if you have manual update on db or dependency to db is not important you can use CDC (chane data capture) and push changes into service broker and your application pop changes from service broker then send them to client by bidirectional http communication technology same as SignalR.