# Can we notifiy .net application to update data from database instead of pooling concept?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My concern is to ping .net web application to pick the updated data from SQL server db and showing the same on ui instead of manual pooling concept. I dnt want to use javascript time intervals.

In research i found [Signal R](http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency) but still asking you all for other concepts which can be opted.

So my question is What are the ways by which i can notify application to retrieve updated data from db?

Comment: Are you asking about Query Notifications in SQL Server? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188323(v=sql.105)

Comment: may be this link will helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875483/i-want-my-database-sql-to-notify-or-push-updates-to-client-application

Comment: @SimonSvensson yes this could be another option. Actually i have stored data into javascript session variables for certain period And not cached on server side. So it would be interesting to interrogate this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Signal R is best one for push notification on web UI in .net.

Answer (score 0):

**Signal R** is the best option to refresh data from database to UI