# Post response to windows application from server using IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, ip, httpresponse

I want to send some notification to windows application after updating particular column of database using that client machine's IP or MAc address if possible.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what type of database are you using?

Comment: Is the application connected to the database, then SqlDependency could be the solution? Otherwise you need to either make the app listen on a socket or request a webservice every few seconds - Or create a simple TCP server in the Windows Application.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875483/i-want-my-database-sql-to-notify-or-push-updates-to-client-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875483/i-want-my-database-sql-to-notify-or-push-updates-to-client-application)

Comment: I tried using SignalR but I think it should not be the answer. I am using SQL Server 2008 as database and it is hosted at server and my application is at client machine.  @Webbanditten,Lei Yang,DarkSquirrel42

Comment: How come SignalR doesnt suit your solution?

Comment: In my case, the response will be return after more than 1 hour or may be in a day so I don't think that it will help, scenario is that client will send some request to server, server will send same request to another server, once 3rd party server process the request it will return to client server. Now I want to notify the client whatever the result is. But I don't have any idea that how can i post that data from server to my windows app... @Webbanditten