# Using SqlDependency with named Queues

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldependency

I have the following code that uses SqlDependency to monitor changes in one of my databases  It works great, except every run it generates its own Queue/Service/Route with a guid in the database:

Class:

```
class SqlWatcher
{
    private string connectionString;
    private string sqlQueue;
    private string listenerQuery;
    private SqlDependency dependency;

    public SqlWatcher(string connectionString, string sqlQueue, string listenerQuery)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
        this.sqlQueue = sqlQueue;
        this.listenerQuery = listenerQuery;
        this.dependency = null;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        ListenForChanges();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(this.connectionString);
    }

    private void ListenForChanges()
    {
        //Remove existing dependency, if necessary
        if (dependency != null)
        {
            dependency.OnChange -= onDependencyChange;
            dependency = null;
        }

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(listenerQuery, connection);

        dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(onDependencyChange);

        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

        command.ExecuteReader();

        //Perform this action when SQL notifies of a change
        performAction();

        connection.Close();
    }

    private void onDependencyChange(Object o, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((args.Source.ToString() == "Data") || (args.Source.ToString() == "Timeout"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine + "Refreshing data due to {0}", args.Source);
            ListenForChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine + "Data not refreshed due to unexpected SqlNotificationEventArgs: Source={0}, Info={1}, Type={2}", args.Source, args.Info, args.Type.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void performAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Performing action");
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string connectionString = @"<MY CONNECTION STRING>"; 
   string sqlQueue = @"NamesQueue";

   //Listener query restrictions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh.aspx
   string listenerQuery = "SELECT Value FROM dbo.Table WHERE Name = 'Test'";

   SqlWatcher w = new SqlWatcher(connectionString, sqlQueue, listenerQuery);
   w.Start();
   Thread.Sleep(10000);
   w.Stop();
}
```

Instead of generating its own queue/service/route everytime, I would like to create them up front and then tell my program to use them.

I went ahead and created these objects on the database :

```
CREATE QUEUE NamesQueue;
CREATE SERVICE NamesService ON QUEUE NamesQueue;
CREATE ROUTE NamesRoute WITH SERVICE_NAME = 'NamesService', ADDRESS = 'LOCAL';
```

and modified my C# code to use this queue and service:

```
...
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, sqlQueue);
...
SqlDependency.Stop(this.connectionString, sqlQueue);
...
dependency = new SqlDependency(command, "service=NamesService;local database=<MY DB>", 0);
...
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString,sqlQueue);
...
```

Making these code changes causes no queues to be created on-the-fly when I run my code, however my code no longer works and my app doesn't recognize changes made to my table/query.

I have spent days trying to figure this out with no success, can anyone offer any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to the code in your question I've finally been able to setup SqlDependency succesfully... Until now I kept getting very cryptic errors (or no errors at all, just the whole thing not working). I wonder why is it so hard to find any good examples about this... Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out - the error was in my SQL CREATE statements.  I was using:

```
CREATE SERVICE NamesService ON QUEUE NamesQueue;
```

but according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190332.aspx, the CREATE SERVICE command needs to take a contract_name parameter in order to be able to allows other dialogs to target the service being created.

So, using the below CREATE statement fixed my issue:

```
CREATE SERVICE NamesService
ON QUEUE NamesQueue
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class - it has the [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/) with memory leaks. Hovewer, you can use an open source realization of the SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses a database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive events about the table changes. This is an usage example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.