# SqlDependency is working with one but not with other table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sqldependency

I have written this class to automate SQLDependencys

```
public class DatabaseChangeAlert
{
    private String connectionString;
    private SqlConnection sc;
    public event EventHandler<DatabaseChangedEvent> DatabaseChangeEvent;
    private String tabelle;
    private String query;
    public DatabaseChangeAlert(String tabelle, String conString)
    {           
        try
        {
            this.tabelle = tabelle;
            this.sc = new SqlConnection(conString); ;//new SqlConnection(GlobalResources.ConnectionString);
            this.connectionString = conString;
            String sel = "";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.syscolumns.name AS Spaltenname " +
                        " FROM dbo.syscolumns INNER JOIN  " +
                        " dbo.sysobjects ON dbo.syscolumns.id = dbo.sysobjects.id " +
                        " WHERE (dbo.sysobjects.xtype = 'U') and dbo.sysobjects.name='" + tabelle + "' ";

                using (SqlDataReader sr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sr.Read())
                    {
                        sel += "["+sr.GetString(0)+"],";
                    }

                }
                sel = sel.Substring(0, sel.Length - 1);
            }
            query = "SELECT " + sel + " from [dbo].[" + tabelle+"]";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
    ~DatabaseChangeAlert()
    {
        if(connectionString!=null)
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
    }
    public void start()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //                log(ex)
        }

        try
        {
            startDependency();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
//                log(ex)
        }
    }
    private void startDependency()
    {            
        // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.
        // Create a new SqlCommand object.
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sc))
        {
            sc.Open();
            // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            // Maintain the refence in a class member.

            // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            // Execute the command.
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                }
            }
            sc.Close();
        }
    }

    void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (e.Info != SqlNotificationInfo.Invalid)
        {
            startDependency();

            if (DatabaseChangeEvent != null)
            {
                DatabaseChangeEvent(this, new DatabaseChangedEvent(tabelle,e.Info));
            }
        }
    }

    public class DatabaseChangedEvent : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly String Tablename;
        public readonly SqlNotificationInfo info;
        public DatabaseChangedEvent(String tablename,SqlNotificationInfo info)
        {
            this.Tablename = tablename;
            this.info = info;
        }
    }
}
```

in my program I use this Class like that:

```
   DatabaseChangeAlert alerttz = new DatabaseChangeAlert("table1", GlobalResources.ConnectionString);
        alerttz.DatabaseChangeEvent += (e,d)=>{
            MessageBox.Show("table1 changed");
        };
        alerttz.start();

        DatabaseChangeAlert alert = new DatabaseChangeAlert("table2", GlobalResources.ConnectionString);
        alert.DatabaseChangeEvent += (e, d) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("table2 changed");
        };
        alert.start();
```

Now my Problem is that when I change anything in table2 I do not get a notification, but when I do the same for table 1 I get a notification!

any ideas what the problem could be?
I also tried to only suscribe for table2...but it remain the same.

Comment: This will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn `dbo.syscolumns` and `dbo.sysobjects` are system views and therefore not vulnerable to sql injection. It is vulnerable if the `tabelle` parameter is supplied by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've repeated your situation and wrote [unit test](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.UnitTests/SqlDependencyTest.cs) (TwoTablesNotificationTest), but didn't find anything. It works fine for me. In this situation you could stop receive notifications from SqlDependency in case of destructor call of some `DatabaseChangeAlert` entity, because it has `SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString)` instruction. Thus, you have to call `SqlDependency.Start` after every `SqlDependency.Stop` to continue receiving events, but destructor is called automatically by garbage collector from parallel thread and it may cause this effect.

And I want to warn you - be careful using SqlDependency class because it has [memory leak problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/). For my project I used open source realization of SqlDependency - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It is very easy to use:

```
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.