# temporarily suspend sqldependency notification for update

Tags: sql-server, sqldependency

I have a SELECT query that I am monitoring using SQLDependency.  Everything works fine, but I would like to temporarily suspend the dependency while I make an UPDATE to the data set that the query is monitoring, one that I know will fire the change notification from the database.

Currently I set a flag that marks the fact that I'm doing the update, let the dependency fire and then I reset it so I can continue monitoring the query.

There has to be a more elegant way to do it than that.

Comment: Could you not Stop the listener and Start it after the update?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class - it has the [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/) with memory leaks. Hovewer, you can use an open source realization of the SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses a database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive events about the table changes. This is an usage example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

With SqlDependecyEx you are able to monitor just INSERT or DELETE, avoiding UPDATE. Hope this helps.