# how to keep sql dependency doing the its purpose

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, notifications, sqldependency

I have a console application.

I wanna keep watching the changes on a specific column in my database table.

I read through internet and I have found that sql dependency is good for my purpose. I started learning about it and I did the following:

1. create a class.
2. In the constructor, I called the static function `start` and I called a function that has all the sql dependency settings.

#### My problem

When I run the application using the `start` click on visual studio 2013, the apps works and then stops. **However**, what I need is that the apps starts working and keep watching for changes in my database's table.

Could you help me please?

#### Code:

This is a very **very** simple c# code.

```
public class MyListener
    {
        public MyListener()
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(getConnectionString());
            this.listen();
        }

        private string getConnectionString()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["popup"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        }
        private void listen()
        {
            string query = "SELECT CallerID FROM TransferToSIP WHERE hasBeenRead = 0";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            using (cmd)
            {
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                dependency.OnChange += new
                   OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                }
            }
        }
        void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Roma");
        }
        void Termination()
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(getConnectionString());
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in absence of the resubscruption. You should call the `listen` method inside of `OnDependencyChange`. I know that it is weird, but it is the SqlDependency class.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful using the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class to monitor changes in the database tables - it has the [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/) with the memory leaks. However, you can use your own realization with DDL triggers and [SQL Service Broker API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848765.aspx) or use one of an open source projects, e.g. [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs):

```
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you answering about something so irrelevance to the question?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I got two answers: the first one is a possible solution, the second one is an advise from my experience.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli My first answer describes the problem in your code which I have faced before in my project.

Comment: your first ansewr really works, but i dont know if that is the real solution or a work arround, i need to know . could you help please? plus one on that question