# SQL Server What is enable_broker for SQLTableDependency

Tags: sql-server, database

In SQL Server, What is enable_broker?
What is the risk?
SQL Table Dependency wants that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-2017

> SQL Server Service Broker provides native support for messaging and
>   queuing applications in the SQL Server Database Engine. This makes it
>   easier for developers to create sophisticated applications that use
>   the Database Engine components to communicate between disparate
>   databases. Developers can use Service Broker to easily build
>   distributed and reliable applications.

2) https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic818423-146-1.aspx

> One risk being if there are already service brokers setup to use that
>   DB they will probably break, and any live connections will be killed
>   and rollback.

3) [Sql Dependency with Service Broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770055/sql-dependency-with-service-broker)

It's not necessary but if you want to see changes you need it or you can use an other service like periodic polling

> Be careful using the SqlDependency class to monitor changes in the
>   database tables - it has the problems with the memory leaks.

I hope it will help you !