# SQL dependency and data refering in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

when we work with sql dependency then we need to always refer a sql like below one `SELECT ActivityDate FROM [bba-reman].MyLog`

i just like to know if i write the above sql this way then does it work

`SELECT TOP 1 ActivityDate FROM [bba-reman].MyLog` OR

`SELECT TOP 5 ActivityDate FROM [bba-reman].MyLog`

i am looking for suggestion and guidance.

```
private void RegisterNotification()
{
    string tmpdata = "";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ActivityDate FROM [bba-reman].MyLog";
            dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr[0] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        tmpdata = dr[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            dr.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //SqlDependency.Stop(connStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. Do you want the TOP queries to be sorted: SELECT TOP 1 ActivityDate FROM [bba-reman] ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC

Comment: yes if i submit that query to sql dependency then does it work? can notify the change ?

Comment: Yes, you can submit that query to SqlDependency and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class has a lot of restrictions as well as the memory leak [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/). An absence of the `TOP` instruction is the one of them. Hovewer, you can use an open source realization of the SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses a database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive events about the table changes. This is an usage example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

With `SqlDependecyEx` you are able to monitor `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` separately and receive actual changed data (`xml`) in the event args object. Filtering incoming messages helps you implement desirable behavior. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the SQL Server Books Online (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx), one of the restrictions for using QueryNotifications is that the statement must not use a TOP expression.  SqlDependency is just a higher level implementation of QueryNotifications that takes care of the Service Broker plumbing.