# Alternative for sqldependency

Tags: c#, signalr, sqldependency

I have a mssql table that holds chat information. It has computed columns, has millions of rows and is being used/populated by an third party application. Now I want to use this table to show chat history on my website and possible in future have the ability to send messages using signalr. 
I did a couple tests using sqldependency and it works but only for specific queries that will not help in my case(I have to exclude the computed columns, cannot order by last msg, cannot set top 100 messages etc)

So my questions is what would be an alternative? using a webservice that polls the database every x seconds?

Side note, i have no influence on the table at all.

Comment: "*what would be an alternative? using a webservice that polls the database every x seconds?*" - yep, pretty much.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by having no influence on the table? Does that mean you don't control how the data is inserted? Wonders can be done with custom helper columns and triggers if the only thing you care about is that the 3rd party's `insert`s and `select`s still have to work. Unless they're using `select *`, of course :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can still use `SqlDependency` if you think a bit more about your actual requirements.

The query you're using to detect changes doesn't have to be the same you use to *fetch* the changes. So you could have

```
select id from chat where chatRoomId = 123
```

as the "detect changes query". This will simply tell you "There's a new message. Or more.", nothing else. Then, to get the actual new rows, you could use your complicated query:

```
select 
 top 100 someComplexColumn, everythingElse 
from chat 
where chatRoomId = 123 
order by messageTime desc
```

As long as the "detect changes query" is good enough at separating the bulk of changes you don't care about from the changes you *do* care about, you're fine. Remember, `SqlDependency` doesn't actually tell you *what* changed, or anything else about the data. It doesn't care about how much data fits the query *now* - it only tracks changes that fit the filter you specify. And since chat messages are usually immutable, you can get away with checking just the `id` column (e.g. "new item"). If your chat messages are editable, you'll have to also add some `changedOn` column to your "detect changes query".

Comment: Wow, so simple but somehow i never thought about this. I just update my code with a simpel query and even with plenty records my OnChange event fires every time. Chat messages arent editable so this should be fine. The only thing i forgot and took me a while to figure out is that i didnt fire the ExecuteReader() for my "detect changes query". Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A good alternative for `SqlDependency` is [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It doesn't have its memory leak [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/) and uses a database trigger plus a native Service Broker notification to receive events about the table changes. This is an usage example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

With `SqlDependecyEx` you are able to monitor `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` separately and receive actual changed data (`xml`) in the event args object. Filtering incoming messages helps you implement desirable behavior. Hope this help.